# Comparing numbers in a text file to a list of numbers in an other textfile

Tags: linux, database, bash, shell, scripting

I have a .txt file containing 4-digit numbers.

sometimes they only contain one 4-digit number, sometimes multiple 4-digit numbers, sometimes they are empty.

example1.txt file:

```
6304
6204
```

example2.txt file:

```
6308
```

example3.txt file:

```
6305
```

example4.txt file:

```
6300
6204
6301
```

example5.txt file:

```
6302
6234
6345
```

What I need to do, is to check if the numbers inside the example file are in a list of numbers I have in an other textfile.

this list looks something like this: (*but with more numbers*)

```
6300 
6301 
6302 
6303 
6304 
6305
```

***for the 'example1.txt' file:**

the number '6204' should be deleted out of the file*(because it's not in the list.)*
the number '6304' must stay in the example file *(it is in the list)*

***for the 'example2.txt' file:**

the number should be deleted and the file should be empty.

***for the 'example3.txt' file:**

the number stays in the example file.

***for the 'example4.txt' file:**

There is more than 1 match in the example file. so everything should be deleted.

***for the 'example5.txt' file:**

Only 6302 should be in the file. the other two should be deleted because they are not in the list.

---

So basicly I want to keep the files that have 1 single match. and those files should only contain the number that matches a number in the list. If there is more than 1 match, the file should be empty. if there are no matches the file should also be empty

On top of all this, I would like to do it in a sh script.

Now my question is:

Is this even possible and how? or do I need to work with a database and other programming language ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you have "a text file" then you say "they contain one or two or no numbers". How many text files do you have? And what is your "other" file called - the list one?

Comment: What if there are 3 numbers in the file and they all match the list? You haven't specified what happens then.

Comment: The amount of textfiles is variable. but I know how to handle that in the script. and indeed It can be possible that there are 3 numbers or even more. but mostly it will only containt 1 number. sometimes 2 numbers en rarely more... In the case of multiple matches they all should be deleted. only one match is allowed. And for the list file lets just call it list.txt or something :) I still need to make it.

Comment: Exmaple 5 says "3204" should stay in the file - it isn't even in the file to start with!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have understood your logic now. I assume your list is stored in file `list.txt` and that you save the following as `marksscript`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# First count total number of matches and store in variable MATCHES
#
MATCHES=0
while read WORD
do
   # Count number of matches for this word
   N=$(grep -c $WORD list.txt)
   [ $N -eq 1 ] && MATCHEDWORD=$WORD
   echo DEBUG: $WORD $N
   ((MATCHES+=N))
done < "$1"

#
# Now we know total number of matches, decide what to do
#
echo DEBUG: Total matches $MATCHES

if [ $MATCHES -ne 1 ]; then
    echo DEBUG: Zero out file - not exactly ONE match
    > "$1"
else
    echo DEBUG: $MATCHEDWORD remains as singleton match
    echo $MATCHEDWORD > "$1"
fi
```

Run like this:

```
chmod +x marksscript
./marksscript example1.txt
```

**OUTPUT**

```
./go example1
DEBUG: 6204 0
DEBUG: 6304 1
DEBUG: Total matches 1
DEBUG: 6304 remains as singleton match

./go example2
DEBUG: Total matches 0
DEBUG: Zero out file - not exactly ONE match

./go example3
DEBUG: 6305 1
DEBUG: Total matches 1
DEBUG: 6305 remains as singleton match

./go example4
DEBUG: 6300 1
DEBUG: 6204 0
DEBUG: 6301 1
DEBUG: Total matches 2
DEBUG: Zero out file - not exactly ONE one match
```

Comment: great ! I will check it tomorrow at work and let you know the results.

Comment: if my example file contains 1 number and the number is in the list, the number stays in the example file. So in that case it works. 
If the number in the file is not in the list.then the number also stays in the example file. in this case the number should be removed. if example1.txt contains one number from the list and 1 number that is not in the list. both get deleted, in this case the one that is in the list should stay in the file & the number that is not in the list should be deleted. I really have no clue on how to change your script to get what i need ?? thanks

Comment: and ofcourse if there are multiple matches in the example file they all should be removed. Sorry for my late response but I had some other work to do first.

Comment: I added some examples to my question to make it clear :)

Comment: Your long comment doesn't make sense. You say "if there is one number and it is in the list, it stays in the file. If there is one number and it is not in the list, it also stays". So it is entirely irrelevant if the number is in the list. Then you say "if a file contains one number in the list and one number not in the list, both get deleted and one should stay and one should be deleted". I can't understand what you want!

Comment: I went on your description that starts "basically..." at the end of your question and implemented that logic, so please try the above on some backed up data! Lines saying "DEBUG:..." can be removed once you understand it all.

Comment: My long comment was a description of how the previous code was working when i tried it on different examples and how it actualy should work :) I'm going to try the new code now.

Comment: Excellent! Pleased to be of service and glad we got there in the end :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not the fastest solution but works:

```
while read line
do 
    sed -i "s/$line//" example1.txt
done < list_textfile.txt
```

It deletes every appearance of the string in each line from your "numbers to check" text file.

**Update:**
This did not what was asked: The above filters out the strings in the list_textfile.txt instead of keeping them.

This should do the right thing:

```
grep -o -f list_textfile.txt example1.txt
```

- -o makes sure only the matching part is shown in the output
- -f allows to specify a file which contains strings to grep for

Comment: This doesn't handle the case where both numbers are in the list and they must both be deleted.

Comment: hi, thank you for the response. 
It's close but exact the opposite. Now de numbers that are in the list get deleted. I need to only keep the numbers that are in the list.

Comment: It does in my case. I put `6304 6204` in `example1.txt`. The `list_textfile.txt` contains each of those number in independent lines. Both values get removed from `example1.txt`

Comment: indeed thats what it does, it deletes the numbers that are in the list. But I need to keep the numbers that are in the list, the rest should be deleted. (thats priority). Deleting everything in the file when there are multiple matches would be a nice extra.