# How to evaluate a list of numbers in a text file with python

Tags: python, numbers, range

I want to check a list of numbers in a text file(P1.txt) with the example format below:

> 68278 63989 64283 65917 66503 68794 68299 64827 65294 68783 68857 68459 66552 63053
>   66588 68162 67316 66742 65008 64327 65320 68307 65798 65198 67868 67157 63526 63917 ...

I tried to do it with the code that I wrote as below:

```
with open("P1.txt") as fin, open("P1_c.txt","w") as fout:
 for line in fin:
  P = line.split()
  for i in P:
    i=P.split()
    if i in range(64600,64799) :
        fout.write("|"+str(P)+"+"+" |")
    elif i in range(67000,67319) :
        fout.write("|"+str(P)+"+"+" |")
    elif i in range(67399,67600) :
        fout.write("|"+str(P)+"+"+" |")
    elif i in range(68000,68699) :
        fout.write("|"+str(P)+"+"+" |")
    elif i in range(69400,69599) :
        fout.write("|"+str(P)+"+"+" |")
    else:
        fout.write("|"+str(P)+"-"+" |")
```

I wanted to check whether these numbers are in the ranges that I defined or not. if they are in these ranges, it should print the number and put a "+" afterwards and if not, put a "-" after the number. But I do not know why it does not work?! :)
I even tried to understand what is discussed in this link "[Comparing numbers in a text file to a list of numbers in an other textfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981948/comparing-numbers-in-a-text-file-to-a-list-of-numbers-in-an-other-textfile)"
But did not get anything.

Comment: Convert i to an int before doing the comparisons, it's still a string: `int(i)`

Comment: Also, unless you're using Python 3, ranges are expense to create and check for containment. Instead, use `if 64600 <= i <= 64799`, for example.

Comment: `i=P.split()` is strange. What do you think it's doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following solution: we get all the integers from the file (at once, not a problem if it is not gigantic) and use a helper function that checks whether a number is in any range for a given collection of tuples indicating the range.

```
>>> def in_ranges(x, range_tuples):
...     return any(t[0] <= x < t[1] for t in range_tuples)
>>>
>>> range_tuples = [(64600,64799), (67000,67319), (67399,67600),
...                 (68000,68699), (69400,69599)]
>>>
>>> with open('testfile') as f:
...     for number in map(int, f.read().split()):
...         if in_ranges(number, range_tuples):
...             sign = '+'
...         else:
...             sign = '-'
...         print '|{}{}|'.format(number, sign)
... 
|68278+|
|63989-|
|64283-|
|65917-|
|66503-|
|68794-|
|68299+|
|64827-|
|65294-|
|68783-|
|68857-|
|68459+|
|66552-|
|63053-|
|66588-|
|68162+|
|67316+|
|66742-|
|65008-|
|64327-|
|65320-|
|68307+|
|65798-|
|65198-|
|67868-|
|67157+|
|63526-|
|63917-|
```

Answer (score 1):

When you read something from a file or `sys.stdin`, Python threats it as a string object. You should create an `int` object from string, and the easiest way to do this is to convert the whole list of strings to a list of ints:

```
 P = map(int, line.split())
```

In this way you apply the function `int` to every object inside `line.split()` (which is a list), and put the result (a list of ints) inside `P`.

Answer (score 0):

`P` is a list of the numbers in each line, and `i` takes in each value successively as the loop proceeds, so there's no need to try and split `i` inside the inner loop. Doing so will bind `i` to the list `[P]`, and your checks will then try to find that list as an element of the `range()` expressions.

You should also convert the strings `P` to integer form before comparing them, per the advice in Peter wood's comment, between the given upper and lower limits.

Answer (score 0):

Reworking your program and without opening the files

```
testlines = [
    '68278 63989 64283 65917 66503 68794 68299 64827 65294 68783 68857 68459 66552 63053',
    '66588 68162 67316 66742 65008 64327 65320 68307 65798 65198 67868 67157 63526 63917'
]


ranges = [(64600, 64799), (67000, 67319), (67399, 67600),
          (68000, 68699), (69400, 69599)]

for a in testlines:

    for num in (int(x) for x in a.split()):

        suffix = '-'
        for lo, hi in ranges:
            if lo <= num < hi:
                suffix = '+'
                break

        print('|' + str(num) + suffix + '|')
```

Output:

```
|68278+|
|63989-|
|64283-|
|65917-|
|66503-|
|68794-|
|68299+|
|64827-|
|65294-|
|68783-|
|68857-|
|68459+|
|66552-|
|63053-|
|66588-|
|68162+|
|67316+|
|66742-|
|65008-|
|64327-|
|65320-|
|68307+|
|65798-|
|65198-|
|67868-|
|67157+|
|63526-|
|63917-|
```